# Identifying formulas from MANOVA in a research paper

Tags: anova, multiple-comparisons, manova, bonferroni, cohens-d

I need to identify the formulas for computing the group differences with Bonferroni corrections and Cohen's d effect size in the following paper (chart on the top of page 6):

[Research Paper](http://www.ncneuropsych.com/research/add-normalize.pdf)

What formula was used to do the group comparisons? Also, what were the degrees of freedom?